# How to reset Ubuntu 13.04 system to default?

Tags: system-settings

I wanna know how to revert the Ubuntu 13.04 to default as first installed (compiz, enviroment, etc..)?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality to do this -  you essentially have to reinstall the operating system from scratch.

However, if you want to ensure that you can do it in the future, you can use a **virtual machine** system which supports snapshots (such as [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_preserve_using_sshot.html) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots)), meaning you can revert to previous states.

Another option is to use a **file system** which supports snapshots, such as [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html) or [ZFS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcya/index.html).

Comment: I found this...
http://www.ubuntudicas.com.br/blog/2012/07/como-resetar-seu-sistema-no-ubuntu-12-04/
Maybe?